# Raspberry PI and co2 sensor (CCS811)

Tags: python, azure, azure-iot-hub

Hello dears Stack Overflow Community, I'm Firas and I'm doing an apprenticeship in System integration, and I have a project to build Co2 Sensor with raspberry Pi, so I was planning to connect it with azure so I can analyze the data there and maybe set a trigger alarm to notify me per Email or ms team channel when the co2 concentration in the room become high, but my problem is when I calculated the price in Azure, the estimated price was high (around 139 Euro per month).
Does anyone here have experience in those type of projects and is there other way to implement the project "in cheaper way", I will be very thankful if someone can guide me and give me suggestions and solutions.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: This seems like more of a question for another StackExchange site, _possibly_ [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Consider using Azure IoT Central. It is free up to 2 devices: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-central

Comment: @asergaz Hi, thank you very much for your answer, do you know where I can find the instructions to send the data from the Raspberry pi to the Azure iot Central and actually how can I configure the co2 sensor???

Comment: There is no E2E sample from a Raspberry Pi co2 sensor to Azure IoT Central that I know of. But you can start by using the Python Sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-send-telemetry-central?pivots=programming-language-python) and then add the libraries responsible to read the data from your Co2 Sensor :).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you deploy an "alarming system" on RPI itself?

(If you don't want to use rpi, I highly recommend Scaleway Stardust as a solution. It's only about 2.5 EUR per month)

Comment: First paragraph is probably better suited as a comment than an answer without supporting details on how one might construct an alarming system on an RPI.  The phrase in the parenthesis probably stands on it's own as an answer without mention of RPI.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Azure IoT Central. It is free up to 2 devices: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/iot-central/

There is no E2E sample from a Raspberry Pi co2 sensor to Azure IoT Central that I know of. But you can start by using the Python Sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-send-telemetry-central?pivots=programming-language-python) and then add the libraries responsible to read the data from your Co2 Sensor.